# Change focused window on set interval

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

On Windows 7, how to do I set it up so that the focused application automatically changes on pre-programmed intervals?

I am running a frame grabber application, a web browser, and a photo slideshow. I would like to display them in a pre-grogrammed order of time intervals. All of the applications need to start (and switch focus) in full screen mode.